# How to pass an array into a function, then call it - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I pass an array into a function and then call that function to print out the array?

I've tried using the code below but it does not print anything to the console.

```
var array_list = [1,2,3,4,5, "token",6, 7, "best","life", "living"];


function printReverse(list){
  for(var i=list; i >= 0; i--){
    console.log(list[i]);
  }
}

printReverse(array_list);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take `list.length - 1` as start value.

```js
function printReverse(list) {
    for (var i = list.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        console.log(list[i]);
    }
}

var array_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "token", 6, 7, "best", "life", "living"];
printReverse(array_list);
```

A shorter approach is to take the length and use a while statement with a truthy check for the index.

```js
function printReverse(list) {
    var i = list.length;
    while (i--) {
        console.log(list[i]);
    }
}

var array_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "token", 6, 7, "best", "life", "living"];
printReverse(array_list);
```

Answer (score 1):

`i=list.length-1` not `i=list`. You have to assign `i` the length of array not the whole array

```js
var array_list = [1,2,3,4,5, "token",6, 7, "best","life", "living"];
function printReverse(list){
  for(var i=list.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    console.log(list[i]);
  }
}

printReverse(array_list);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the length as index value to `i` not array itself. because when you compare an array with `>=0` this turns out to be `false` and your loop ends their itself.

```js
console.log([1,2,3] >= 0)
```

```js
var array_list = [1,2,3,4,5, "token",6, 7, "best","life", "living"];


function printReverse(list){
  for(var i=list.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    console.log(list[i]);
  }
}

printReverse(array_list);
```